Lines in a hypersurface
Let $X$ be the quadric hypersurface in the $\mathbb{P}^4(\mathbb{C})$ defined by the equation
$$x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=0.$$
I am using this example to understand how to compute the conditions for a variety to contains lines. My approach is to consider the map
$$ f: \mathbb{P}^1\to \mathbb{P}^4$$
$$[a:b]\mapsto [t_0a+s_0b:t_1a+s_1b:t_2a+s_2b:t_3a+s_3b: t_4a+s_4b]$$
given by linear polynomials, with $t_i,s_i\in \mathbb{C}$. Now I would say that $f(\mathbb{P}^1)\subset X$ if and only if
$$ \sum_{i=0}^4 (t_ia+s_ib)^2=0.$$
But there should be other equations I don't see: the reason is that $X$ is a $3$-dimensional hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^4$, hence a line in $X$ should be given by (at least) 2 polynomial equations.
More generally, a line in $\mathbb{P}^n$ should be contained into a hypersurface if it satisfies at least $n-2$-equations. How to find these other equations?

The equation has to hold for all values of $s_i,t_i$. This is far from an equation in the ambient homogeneous coordinates on $\Bbb P^4$.

Expand the left hand side of your equation to get $$ \left( \sum_{i=0}^4 t_i^2 \right)a^2 + \left( \sum_{i=0}^4 2t_is_i \right)ab + \left( \sum_{i=0}^4 s_i^2 \right)b^2 =0 $$
The LHS is a homogenous polynomial in $ a,b $ and is identically zero hence, the coefficients are equal to 0. We get three equations: $ \sum_{i=0}^4 t_i^2 = 0 $, $ \sum_{i=0}^4 s_i^2 = 0 $ and $ \sum_{i=0}^4 2t_is_i = 0 $
The first two of these are 'obvious' equations: If the line between the points $ [t_0: \ldots : t_4] $ and $ [s_0 : \ldots : s_4] $ lies on $ X $, the points themselves better lie on $ X $ too. The third equation is exactly the condition for the entire line to be on $ X $.
